# Sitecore: How to read complex form input fields into Items?

Tags: forms, input, sitecore

I have a form with two input fields which match my Sitecore template: One text field and one General Link field.

Now I want to read both input fields into an item. For the first text field it works like this:

```
newItem.Fields["Comment Author"].Value = txtAuthor.Text;
```

But it doesn't work for the complex field type Link:

```
newItem.Fields["Comment Author Link"].Value = txtLink.Text;
```

The item is created in Sitecore, but the link field is empty. So how can I read these complex fields like Links and DropDowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex fields you can cast those fields to the correct type.  You will find the types for all Sitecore fields in the Sitecore.Data.Fields namespace.

For your link field you would have to do something like this:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField myLink = newItem.Fields["Comment Author Link"];
myLink.Url = txtLink.Text;
```

Note that Sitecore treats Internal Links, Media Links, and External links differently so you should make sure to review what type of link you are looking to utilize.  Take a look here -> [GeneralLink in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919954/generallink-in-sitecore) for some more detail in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I still can't get it to work. I fill in web.de into the link input field, but the field in the created item is filled with {2F4CA88F-2DDE-4028-B2F3-6FEF37E13199}. This is what I do:

LinkField linkField = newItem.Fields["Comment Author Link"];
linkField.Url = txtLink.Text;

linkField.TargetID = newItem.ID;
linkField.Target = "_blank";
linkField.LinkType = "external";

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the Field first and then saving it.

Ex:

```
var link = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)newItem.Fields["Comment Author Link"]
link.Url = txtLink.Link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it to work with this:

```
newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();

LinkField linkField = new LinkField(newItem.Fields["Comment Author Website"]);
linkField.Url = txtLink.Text;
linkField.TargetID = newItem.ID;
linkField.Title = txtLink.Text;
linkField.Text = txtLink.Text;
linkField.Target = "_blank";
linkField.LinkType = "external";

newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Thank you very much!