# Render URL without Code Behind File on Sitecore 7.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, facebook-opengraph

I'm attempting to generate opengraph tags using the following:

```
<meta content="<%= ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph URL"]).Url %>" property="og:url" />
<meta content="<%= ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph Image"]).Url %>" property="og:image" />
```

That returns:

```
<meta content="/Site/Site/Home/Page Directory/Page Name property="og:url">
<meta content="/sitecore/media library/Images/Social Image Directory/Image" property="og:image">
```

I'm hoping to get "http://www.example.com/page-directory/page-name" and "http://www.example.com/media-library/images/social-image-directory/image.jpg" as the output.

Using Sitecore 7.0 and not accessing the .cs file, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the LinkManager options for a url with ServerUrl and use the .MediaItem to get the target MediaItem.
Try somethings for a image field:

```csharp
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Resources.Media" %>
    <%
        var ogImage = string.Empty;
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField ogImageField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph Image"];
        if (ogImageField != null && ogImageField.MediaItem != null)
        {
            var options = new MediaUrlOptions();
            options.AbsolutePath = true;
            options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
             ogImage = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(ogImageField.MediaItem, options);
        }

         %><meta content="<%= ogImage %>" property="og:image">
```

You can define the targetHostName in the web.config or include file `<sites><site ..... targetHostName="www.yoursite.com">`

See [#Tip 20 Url with hostname for example a og:image](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-tips-and-tricks.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The URL property will not produce correct URL's for internal items.

You could use this instead:

```csharp
<%= LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph URL"].TargetItem) %>
```

and this for the media item

```csharp
<%= Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph Image"].TargetItem) %>
```

However, you should note that this assumes that the Link field definitely points to an internal item (It might be pointing at an external URL). If you're able to write more than just isolated inline statements, then I would recommend using the LinkField's `IsInternal` property to perform this check.

The answer on this SO question is very comprehensive: [GeneralLink in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919954/generallink-in-sitecore)