# How to get the url path for a general link in Sitecore 7.2 C#

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am quite new to Sitecore and C#, and I've been struggling with something for the past few days, so I hope one of you guys can help me.

I've just upgraded from Sitecore 6 to 7 and there's been some changes. The following code used to work in Sitecore 6, but the way you get the url for the LinkField is not working anymore.

```
 protected string writeBalloon(Item targetItem)
    {
        string balloonString = "";

        Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkfield = targetItem.Fields["Link"];

        balloonString += "<a class='balloon-link' href='" + linkfield.Url + "'>";
        balloonString += "<div class='balloon'>";

        balloonString += "<h3>";
        balloonString += targetItem.Fields["Title"];
        balloonString += "</h3>";
        balloonString += "<p>";
        balloonString += targetItem.Fields["Text"];

        balloonString += "</p>";
        balloonString += "</div>";
        balloonString += "</a>";

        return balloonString;
    }
```

I think I have read/tried all articles on google regarding this matter, but I still can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your link field type first, Using **linkfield.Url** works only with External link type in sitecore , Here is how your code should look like :

```
public String LinkUrl(Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField lf)
{
    switch (lf.LinkType.ToLower())
    {
      case "internal":
        // Use LinkMananger for internal links, if link is not empty
        return lf.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(lf.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "media":
        // Use MediaManager for media links, if link is not empty
        return lf.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(lf.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "external":
        // Just return external links
        return lf.Url;
      case "anchor":
        // Prefix anchor link with # if link if not empty
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lf.Anchor) ? "#" + lf.Anchor : string.Empty;
      case "mailto":
        // Just return mailto link
        return lf.Url;
      case "javascript":
        // Just return javascript
        return lf.Url;
      default:
        // Just please the compiler, this
        // condition will never be met
        return lf.Url;
    }
}



protected string writeBalloon(Item targetItem)
{
        string balloonString = "";

        Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkfield = targetItem.Fields["Link"];

        balloonString += "<a class='balloon-link' href='" + LinkUrl(linkfield) + "'>";
        balloonString += "<div class='balloon'>";

        balloonString += "<h3>";
        balloonString += targetItem.Fields["Title"];
        balloonString += "</h3>";
        balloonString += "<p>";
        balloonString += targetItem.Fields["Text"];

        balloonString += "</p>";
        balloonString += "</div>";
        balloonString += "</a>";

        return balloonString;
}
```

**`Note`** : The code snippet taken for the **LinkUrl()** method is taken from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920525/1218297)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 8):

Since Sitecore 7.2, a method `GetFriendlyUrl()` was added to the `LinkField` class to solve this.

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkfield = targetItem.Fields["Link"];
var url = linkfield.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

See [GeneralLink in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919954/generallink-in-sitecore/28299654#28299654)