# Sitecore MVC redirect to another page

Tags: sitecore-mvc

I had a requirement in my Sitecore MVC to display Carousel Items in the Homepage and when click the View More it will redirect to another page for user to view the full content

How could I achieve this? Currently all my items in Sitecore has Controller Rendering in Presentation Details. I'm just not sure how to get the GUID of the Carousel Item using  then in the controller action it will redirect on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have carousel items under one folder in your content tree in Sitecore with some specific fields for each carousel item like image, title ...etc, so you should have field in the carousel items with for link:

**Name: Link 
 Type : GeneralLink**

link each carousel item to the proper page ,And then in your view you can read the page URL:

and you can use this method to get link URL to the page from your carousel component :

```
public String LinkUrl(Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField lf)
{
    switch (lf.LinkType.ToLower())
    {
      case "internal":
        // Use LinkMananger for internal links, if link is not empty
        return lf.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(lf.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "media":
        // Use MediaManager for media links, if link is not empty
        return lf.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(lf.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "external":
        // Just return external links
        return lf.Url;
      case "anchor":
        // Prefix anchor link with # if link if not empty
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lf.Anchor) ? "#" + lf.Anchor : string.Empty;
      case "mailto":
        // Just return mailto link
        return lf.Url;
      case "javascript":
        // Just return javascript
        return lf.Url;
      default:
        // Just please the compiler, this
        // condition will never be met
        return lf.Url;
    }
}
```

and in your carousel view :

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = carouselItem.Fields["Link"];
var pageUrl = linkField.LinkUrl();
```

This code is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919954/generallink-in-sitecore/19920525#19920525)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prepare appropriate model object in the controller action and then pass it to the view.

Model class:

```
public class CarouselModel 
{
    public List<Item> CarouselItems { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Carousel()
{
    var model = new CarouselModel
    {
        CarouselItems = /* get appropriate items dependent on your logic */
    };

    return View("~/Views/renderings/Carousel.cshtml", model);
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model CarouselModel

<div>
    @foreach(var carouselItem in Model.CarouselItems)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField targetLinkField = carouselItem.Fields["Target"];     
        <a href="@Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(targetLinkField.TargetItem)">Some link</a>
    }
</div>
```

Example above assumes that template of 'Carousel Item' contains 'Target' link field.